# How can I make an object appear or emerge from a flat surface?

Tags: modeling, animation

I want to have an object come out of a surface as if the surface is a portal or something similar, like Mary Poppins' bag.

How can I accomplish this. My method was to surround the object with a boolean difference box and animate it moving out of the box. However, this has some rendering glitches when I try to animate it.

Comment: Do you want the "portal" surface to be visible?

Comment: Not necessarily. The main effect I am looking for is something appearing out of nowhere. If I need a surface I guess I can place "false" portal.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7793/599

Answer (score 1):

If both objects are manifold and don't have any self-intersections, the boolean method *should* work.

However, booleans are sometimes finicky for no reason, so here's another approach:

1. Move the object you want to appear to a empty layer (e.g. layer 2), keeping the rest of the scene on layer 1
2. Make a bounding cube as if you were going to use a boolean modifier, but instead give it a *holdout* material which is only visible to the camera (so that it doesn't cast a shadow):

   [image]
3. Create a new renderlayer and set it to only layer 2. Also change the existing renderlayer to only layer 1:

   [image]
4. Enable *Transparent* in *Render settings > Film*
5. Set up the composite nodes

   [image]

**Result**:

[image]

The shadow is an obvious limitation, but I can't think of a good workaround aside from just removing the shadow completely..

Comment: This seems like an interesting technique. I will try it. Regarding the boolean modifier, I had rendering issues at specific frames, I'm guessing because some faces were overlapping or something.

Comment: @AGibbons yes, booleans are known to have problems with pieces of geometry (verts, edges, faces) from the two objects occupying the exact same location.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the opposite effect? I mean, to show the object only while it is inside the cube, @gandalf3 ?